# Static linking into swig wrapper

Tags: cmake, swig

I have a working swig wrapper for C++ library(mylib.so). And now I want to link mylib.so to the wrapper library(mylib_wrapper.so) statically. Currently I build my wrapper with cmake.

1. Should a wrapped library be a static library(not a dynamic) if I want
   have a static linking in my swig wrapper?
2. What modifications I should do in my interface/cmake files?

Currently I have following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
find_package(Ruby)
include_directories(${RUBY_INCLUDE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
set(MODULE_NAME ruby_module)
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

set_source_files_properties(${MODULE_NAME}.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_module(${MODULE_NAME} ruby ${MODULE_NAME}.i ruby_wrapper.cpp)
swig_link_libraries(${MODULE_NAME} ${MAIN_LIBRARY_NAME})
swig_link_libraries(${MODULE_NAME} ${RUBY_LIBRARIES})
```

And .i file:

```
%module ruby_module

%{
#include "ruby_wrapper.h"
%}

%import std_string.i

%include "ruby_module.h"
```

And headers file:
**ruby_module.h and ruby_wrapper.h** are have the same content.

```
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();

public:
  std::string myfunc(const std::string& path);
};
```

In the ruby_wrapper.cpp file is overwrited functions of mylib.so .

Comment: Difficult for us to say what modifications you need to make without knowing what you've already got. Please can you add enough detail that we can reproduce your situation without having to resort to guessing.

Comment: @Flexo Ok. I edited my question and added more details.

Comment: @Flexo from swig documentation, I found info about "embed.i" which uses for python wrapper?

Comment: @Flexo for ruby I found only this in doc : The usual procedure for adding a new module to Ruby involves finding the Ruby source, adding an entry to the ext/Setup file, adding your directory to the list of extensions in the file, and finally rebuilding Ruby.

Comment: @Flexo to the previous comment:
ext/Setup file - What is this file?